# Hosting a Subdomain

Tags: web-hosting

I have purchased a domain from GoDaddy.

example.com

However, I am hosting the site on a different service provider which is hemsida24.se

Things work fine except that now I want to host a sub domain on my GoDaddy account. I have already created a subdomain as subdomain.example.com using cPanel but when i browse to the sub domain URL I always get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: You're going to have to tell us more about how you set this up. Otherwise we don't have enough to go on here.

Comment: Where is the DNS hosted? ie. Where are the NAMESERVERS pointing?

Comment: You will have to go to your GoDaddy DNS settings and add the sub-domain. This should be a simple thing. Creating it in your cPanel will not do it (as far as I know). It is also possible you will just have to wait for a period. Call their tech support. They are good and free.

Comment: "I have already created a subdomain as subdomain.example.com using cPanel" — Then you either set up the DNS wrong, or you are looking at cached DNS results and have to wait for the changes catch up with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create an A record and then enter host name (subdomain.example.com) and then add the ip address of the server.

For Godaddy follow these steps.

1. Log into account
2. Open the Domain Manager
3. Click the domain you are working with
4. Click "Total DNS Control and MX Records"
5. The first group in this area should be A (Host), on the top right of
   this bar, click Add New A Record
6. Enter the host name, in my case it was "subdomain.example.com"
7. Enter the IP address of the server you wish to point at.

Here's the [source](https://css-tricks.com/put-a-subdomain-on-a-different-server/).